# Are there or have there been any Christian traditions that follow Kosher food laws?

Tags: judaism, diet, jewish-culture

Kosher food laws are part of Judaism, from which Christianity grew.

But what Christian denominations or traditions follow, or historically have observed Kosher food laws?

Comment: To close voters: unless there are many such denominations, which has not been demonstrated, I don't see how this can be considered "too broad."  Too broad means that "good answers would be too long for this format," not "I'd have to look far and wide to find an answer."

Answer (score 4):

The [Ethiopian Orthodox Tewahedo Church](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethiopian_Orthodox_Tewahedo_Church#Similarities_to_Judaism) maintains a practice that resembles Kosher food laws. (There are similarities and differences: the members of this church avoid pork, but they do commonly mix meat and dairy products in their cuisine.)

Comment: Their day also starts at sundown.

Comment: @KenGraham That is interesting,when does a Day start(biblical)?

Comment: [Most countries start the day at midnight. So 7:00 a.m. in East Africa Time, Ethiopia's time zone, is 1:00 in daylight hours in local Ethiopian time. At 7:00 p.m., East Africa Time, Ethiopians start over again, so it's 1:00 on their 12-hour clock.](http://www.pri.org/stories/2015-01-30/if-you-have-meeting-ethiopia-you-better-double-check-time)

Answer (score 4):

If by 'kosher' you mean biblically defined food that is clean / unclean in places like Leviticus 11, and not Talmud / Mishnah (Judisam); then the answer to your question 'Are there or have there been any Christian traditions that follow Kosher food laws?', is yes there are.

A few that come to mind are:

1. **Seventh-Day Adventists**

> *"Adventists are known for presenting a "health message" that recommends vegetarianism and advocate adherence to the kosher laws in Leviticus 11. The observance of which means, abstinence from pork, shellfish, and other animals proscribed as "unclean". "* — **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seventh-day_Adventist_Church#Health_and_diet)**

2. **Worldwide Church of God (Pre 1990s)**

> *"The church strictly observed the Saturday Sabbath, annual festivals described in the twenty-third chapter of Leviticus, and strongly advocated the clean meats listed in Leviticus 11."* — **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grace_Communion_International#Historical_teachings_under_Armstrong)**

3. **Church of God (Seventh-Day)**

> *"... we confidently call upon believers to distinguish between clean and unclean animals in their diet, for both spiritual and physical benefit"* — **[Eating the Bible Way](https://baonline.org/eating-the-bible-way/), A teaching booklet from the Church of God (Seventh Day)**

4. **Restored Church of God**

> *"... includes belief in the impending Apocalypse followed by the millennial reign of Jesus Christ on Earth, along with Old Testament dietary provisions, tithing, observance of seventh-day Sabbath, bans on holidays and festivals with pagan roots like Christmas and Easter ..."* — **[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restored_Church_of_God#Doctrines)**

I suspect a more thorough study would lead to the discovery of additional ones.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). For more on what this site is about, see: [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808/20394). Your answer is a good one, I think, up until you mention Islam—which is not a *Christian* tradition, and therefore does not fit as an answer to the question asked. I would recommend editing that part out of your answer.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden Ok. Yeah I wasn't sure if the OP wanted 'other traditions' that followed or historically have their roots as they've stated. Sorry, I should've viewed that within the context of their overall question. I'll edit it now, thanks