# Can Christians still eat meat with blood in it?

Tags: sin, leviticus, law, noah

These are the verses in question that prohibits eating meat with blood in it:

> "But you must not eat meat that has its lifeblood still in it. 5 And
>   for your lifeblood I will surely demand an accounting. I will demand
>   an accounting from every animal."- **Genesis 9:4-5**.
>
> "‘Suppose someone eats meat that still has blood in it. It does not
>   matter whether they are an Israelite or an outsider. I will turn
>   against them if they eat it. I will separate them from their people."-
>   **Leviticus 17:10**.

Is this just an OT ceremonial law or something else?

Comment: Related https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/46207/23657

Comment: New Testament strictly forbids eating blood:KJV Acts 15
28 For it seemed good to the Holy Ghost, and to us, to lay upon you no greater burden than these necessary things;
29 That ye abstain from meats offered to idols, and from blood, and from things strangled, and from fornication: from which if ye keep yourselves, ye shall do well. Fare ye well.

Comment: @OneFace If you're thinking of adding Acts 15:28-29, there is [another duplicate](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/46207/how-have-mainstream-christian-denominations-interpreted-the-acts-command-to-abst)

Comment: I have suggested on the [Meta Site](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6860/requesting-reopening) that this be asked in [Biblical Hermeneutics](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions). The question is not about the Law of Moses as the instruction is to all mankind in Adam.

Answer (score 0):

As [this question explains](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/52717/are-there-or-have-there-been-any-christian-traditions-that-follow-kosher-food-la), some denominations do still follow Old Testament food laws, so would likely answer **"no, they can't"**.

However, many Christians also take Jesus' words in Mark 7 to explain that Christians do not have to follow Old Testament food laws, so would likely answer **"yes, they can"**.

> For it doesn't go into their heart but into their stomach, and then out of the body." (In saying this, Jesus declared all foods clean.) [Mark 7:19 (NIV®)](https://biblehub.com/niv/mark/7.htm)

Comment: The instruction about blood is to all mankind in the new age (after the Flood). All humanity (not just Jews) are to refrain from partaking of blood with the flesh. My own view is that natural mankind does not partake of the blood of the sacrifice. Repentance is required. Then faith. Then one partakes of the blood of Christ, in spirit. The life is in the blood. Just as Adam was banished from Eden (and so from the Tree of Life) , so is natural humanity denied the blood. Dust thou art and to dust shalt thou return : is all that man in Adam can expect.